# How to Get profile large image from Android Facebook Graph-API

Tags: android, facebook, image, api

I want to show the users profile picture in a imageview. When I try to call the graph-api.
It will return the image but the size is too much small like an small icon.can anyone help me that how can I get a large image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best you could do is request the large profile picture using

```
http://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/picture?type=large
```

[For more info, Check the facebook graph api documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

> You can specify the picture size you want with the type argument, which should be one of ***square*** (50x50), ***small*** (50 pixels wide, variable height), ***normal*** (100 pixels wide, variable height), and ***large*** (about 200 pixels wide, variable height)

Comment: what is the "OBJECT_ID" here.

Comment: use the profile id of the user that you want the profile picture of

Comment: @RajaReddyP actually the options only include (variable height) except for type `square` where you get a square (50x50)... However if u choose type `normal` it will probably have a height close to 100..